# need help sorting xml file using ruby nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to sort the following xml file such that the Table nodes under Tables are sorted by 
their Name node.  I also want the Columns under the Columns node to be their Name node.
How can I do this using ruby and nokogiri?

I hope this example gives you the idea of how I want it sorted (it doesnt include the whole file, too much typing):

```
    ....
          <Table>
             <Name>Account</Name>
             ...
          </Table>
          <Table>
             <Name>Item</Name>
          </Table>
             <Name>Order</Name>
          <Table>
             <Name>Product</Name>
             ...
                <Column>
                   <Name>description</Name>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                   <Name>productid</Name>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                   <Name>productname</Name>
                </Column>
            ...
          </Table>
    ....
```

Unfortunately, I can't upload the disorganized file. So I'll have to post it here:

```
   <Db xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tedsdb.com/schemas" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tedsdb.com/schemas/Db.xsd">
      <Name>Store</Name>
      <Version>3</Version>
      <Catalog name="Store" version="3"></Catalog>
      <Tables>
         <Table>
            <Name>Product</Name>
            <Columns>
               <Column>
                  <Name>productid</Name>
                  <Length>11</Length>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Name>productname</Name>
                  <Length>25</Length>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Name>description</Name>
                  <Length>250</Length>
                  <Properties>
                     <Property>
                        <Name>Store_NAME</Name>
                        <Value>desc</Value>
                     </Property>
                  </Properties>
               </Column>
            </Columns>
         </Table>
         <Table>
            <Name>Order</Name>
            <Columns>
               <Column>
                  <Name>orderid</Name>
                  <Length>11</Length>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Name>userid</Name>
                  <Length>11</Length>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Name>orderdate</Name>
                  <Properties>
                     <Property>
                        <Name>NAME_IS_KEYWORD</Name>
                        <Value>desc_</Value>
                     </Property>
                     <Property>
                        <Name>Store_NAME</Name>
                        <Value>desc</Value>
                     </Property>
                  </Properties>
               </Column>
            </Columns>
            <Key>
               <Name>Order_PK</Name>
               <Type>PRIMARY</Type>
               <ColumnNames>
                  <Name>topid</Name>
               </ColumnNames>
            </Key>
         </Table>
         <Table>
            <Name>Item</Name>
            <Columns>
               <Column>
                  <Name>itemid</Name>
                  <Length>11</Length>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Name>itemname</Name>
                  <Length>250</Length>
               </Column>
            </Columns>
            <Key>
               <Name>Product_PK</Name>
               <Type>PRIMARY</Type>
               <ColumnNames>
                  <Name>topid</Name>
               </ColumnNames>
            </Key>
         </Table>
         <Table>
            <Name>Account</Name>
            <Columns>
               <Column>
                  <Name>accountid</Name>
                  <Length>11</Length>
               </Column>
               <Column>
                  <Name>accountname</Name>
                  <Length>250</Length>
               </Column>
            </Columns>
            <Key>
               <Name>Product_PK</Name>
               <Type>PRIMARY</Type>
               <ColumnNames>
                  <Name>topid</Name>
               </ColumnNames>
            </Key>
         </Table>
      </Tables>
      <Links>
         <Link>
            <Name>Accounts.orders.link</Name>
         </Link>
      </Links>
   </Db>
```

After trying answer proposed, I tried the following code. I'm using aptana studio on windows 7. The variable **doc** is not null and actually has the loaded file, but **doc.at(//Tables)** returns nil, and so it fails from there:

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

f = File.open("test.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
f.close

tables = doc.at('//Tables');

tables.search('./Table').each do |t|
  columns = t.at('//Columns')
  columns.search('./Column').sort_by { |l| l.at('Name').text }.each do |col|
    columns << col
  end
end

puts doc.to_xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort nodes just reinsert them into the parent node in the order you want them:

```
tables = doc.at('//Tables')
tables.search('./Table').sort_by{|t| t.at('Name').text}.each do |table|
  tables << table
end
```

Comment: I noticed there are problems with your xml. Fix those and it will work.

Comment: I did and I was able to sort the tables. I noticed that when I tried to do this for the columns.. I only get the columns of the first table sorted. I updated the code to my attempt to sort the Columns.

Comment: Because `t.at('//Columns')` gives the same columns every time. You want: `t.at('./Columns')` instead.